# UITextView - how to make it look like in the IB?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am initializing a text view from my code, not from the interface builder and it appears to be just a white rectangle. I want it to have the same rounded shape as is in the interface builder. How can I achieve this?

The same question concerning UITextView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text view is rectangular even in IB. A UITextField has rounded corners. For that, just set the borderStyle property of UITextField to UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect

Answer (score 1):

You maybe confusing UITextView with UITextField.

UITextField has a optional rounded rectangle border.  UITextView is just the text, no border.  You have to bring your own border to the party and place it behind the UITextView.